# iText Flatten PDF

Tags: itext

I have PDF template with a large text-box. Based on the size of the content, the textbox comes-up with a vertical scroll bar. But issue comes up when I flatten the PDF using PDFStamper, the text box does not have the scroll bar and user see only half of the content.
Is there way to allow scroll bar in the text box after flatten the pdf?
Please note that while designing the textbox in the template we have enabled scroll bar option.

Answer (score 1):

No. Flattening a PDF effectively disables interactivity. What your printer kicks out is what you see on screen. One work around is to drop the font size on the field for long items. Another option is to make the PDF read-only instead flattening it. See [this post](http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Provide-Scroll-in-Flatten-content-td4439793.html) from the office iText mailing list for more.